# When does the arp cache get emptied?

Tags: macos, unix

does anyone know when the [arp cache](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) in OS X Lion gets emptied? Or which automatism causes it to get emptied? Is it a time period, which can be set somewhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to arp(4) on an OS X Lion system:

> ```
>  The ARP cache is stored in the system routing table as dynamically-created host
>  routes.  The route to a directly-attached Ethernet network is installed as a
>  ``cloning'' route (one with the RTF_CLONING flag set), causing routes to individual
>  hosts on that network to be created on demand.  These routes time out periodically
>  (normally 20 minutes after validated; entries are not validated when not in use).
> ```

You can manually manage the ARP table using the `arp` command.